# One value for a group of columns in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the columns like this, all columns coming from three different tables.

```
GROUPID     COMPANYID CUSTID    DEAL
121         A           1       DEAL1
121         A           1       DEAL2
121         A           1       DEAL3
121         B           2       DEAL1
121         B           2       DEAL2
121         B           2       DEAL3
```

i want the columns like

```
GROUPID     COMPANYID CUSTID    DEAL
121         A           1       DEAL1
                                DEAL2
                                DEAL3
            B           2       DEAL1
                                DEAL2
                                DEAL3
```

Can you help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a SQL thing. Fix it in the presentation instead.

Comment: If you're using an application language such as Java, PHP, or C#, then handle this requirement there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am just enhancing Tim answer by adding lag() window function

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 121 AS GROUPID, 'A' AS COMPANYID, 1 AS CUSTID, 'DEAL1' AS DEAL FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 121, 'A', 1, 'DEAL2' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 121, 'A', 1, 'DEAL3' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 121, 'B', 2, 'DEAL1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 121, 'B', 2, 'DEAL2' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 121, 'B', 2, 'DEAL3' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 123, 'c', 2, 'DEAL1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 123, 'c', 2, 'DEAL2' FROM dual
),
cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GROUPID, COMPANYID, CUSTID ORDER BY DEAL) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)
,cte1 as(
SELECT
    GROUPID,
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN COMPANYID END AS COMPANYID,
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CUSTID END AS CUSTID,
    DEAL
FROM cte t
ORDER BY
    GROUPID,
    t.COMPANYID,
    CUSTID,
    DEAL) select case when lag(GROUPID)over(order by GROUPID)=GROUPID
    then null else GROUPID end Gid,COMPANYID,CUSTID,DEAL from cte1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9fdb65b9fa504d79b3aeb979bae1bbd7)

Answer (score 1):

Well, from my point of view, this is the *client* problem, not necessarily SQL one. Any decent reporting tool (such as Oracle Reports Builder, Oracle Apex Classic report, ...) is capable of **breaking** data on columns you choose.

Even the good, old SQL*Plus knows how to do that.

This is your current result:

```
SQL> select * from three_tables order by groupid, companyid, custid, deal;

   GROUPID COMPANYID      CUSTID DEAL
---------- ---------- ---------- -----
       121 A                   1 DEAL1
       121 A                   1 DEAL2
       121 A                   1 DEAL3
       121 B                   2 DEAL1
       121 B                   2 DEAL2
       121 B                   2 DEAL3

6 rows selected.
```

**Break** (as I said):

```
SQL> break on groupid on companyid on custid
SQL>
SQL> select * from three_tables order by groupid, companyid, custid, deal;

   GROUPID COMPANYID      CUSTID DEAL
---------- ---------- ---------- -----
       121 A                   1 DEAL1
                                 DEAL2
                                 DEAL3
           B                   2 DEAL1
                                 DEAL2
                                 DEAL3

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

I suggest you do the same - set the *breaking* option in a tool you use.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be done in SQL. You should be doing this in the reporting tool that you use. GroupID, CompanyID and CustID can be the dimensions and Deal can be the measure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in SQL, then you probably need to use as many analytic functions as you have columns to outpout

```sql
select 
    case when GROUPID != lag(GROUPID, 1, 999999999)over(partition by GROUPID order by GROUPID) then GROUPID else null end GROUPID
,   case when COMPANYID != lag(COMPANYID, 1, 'ZZZZZZZZZ')over(partition by GROUPID, COMPANYID order by COMPANYID) then COMPANYID else null end COMPANYID
,   case when CUSTID != lag(CUSTID, 1, 999999999)over(partition by GROUPID, COMPANYID, CUSTID order by CUSTID) then CUSTID else null end CUSTID
,   case when DEAL != lag(DEAL, 1, 'ZZZZZZZZZ')over(partition by GROUPID, COMPANYID, CUSTID, DEAL order by DEAL) then DEAL else null end DEAL
from your_table
;
```